# How to read both integers and doubles from txt fle

Tags: java

i have a text file and i want to read the integers and doubles. I dont know how many values i have to read. The first value in the line is always the integer and the second is always the double. I want to save the value of the first line seperately.

```
 200
  11010 0.004
    500 0.02
    637 0.018
```

How to create 2 arrays and save the values, so i can  use them later? I am not allowed to create a new class. I tried to use Point but cant store doubles.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        int cores= scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print(cores);
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        int x = scanner.nextInt();
        double y = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("x");}
```

I' ve tried the code above but throws out Exception

Comment: The best method is not to either make 2 of anything or to make arrays; it's instead to make a class to hold the (int, double) pair (maybe named something like `Sample`), and to add items to a `List<Sample>` until you reach the end of input.

Comment: For you, probably using a `Scanner`.

Comment: That depends what you consider "best". If you are looking for ease of use, use Scanner, if you are looking for speed, use InputStreamReader and implement custom parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple file handling approach to read the file line by line, For the first line you can use a flag to mark the line and sent the file to remote location you want to save the data. Then for all later lines you can split the string on the basis of " " (space). Post which once you have stripped the elements of the resulting array you can typecast and append the element at first index to integer array. And the second element (typecast before append) to the double array. This shall work absolutely fine with any length of file.

A demo code for the same is as following:

```
public class ReadLineByLine  
{  
    public static void main(String args[])  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("Demo.txt");       
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(fis);   
            String tempLineData = "";
            int flag = 0;
            String[] elements;
            List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>(
            List<Float> floats = new ArrayList<Float>(
            while(sc.hasNextLine())  
            {  
                if(flag == 0){
                    // Place the operation with the first line here 
                    flag++;
                }
                tempLineData=sc.nextLine();        
                elements = tempLineData.split(" ");
                ints.add((int)elements[0].trim());
                floats.add((float)elements[1].trim());
            }  
            sc.close();     
        }  
        catch(IOException e)  
        {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  
}
```